# Ruby Sinatra templating system with jQuery syntax

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I found a templating system for Sinatra that it uses a jQuery-like syntax for matching elements in an HTML file to do loops, printing information, and all you would find on a templating system. I hate mixing Ruby code with HTML code, or abstracting languages (such as HTML). So this one looked like a perfect fit. Anyone know the name of it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are mixing a couple concepts.

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is used to do CSS and XPath searches through HTML and XML files and lets you iterate though repeating structures, but it does have anything to do with templates. The CSS aspect of Nokogiri uses a jQuery compatible CSS selector, making it easy to piggyback on any HTML/jQuery/CSS knowledge you have.

For templates I'd recommend [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), or [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/), if you want something similar to what comes with Rails, or [HAML](http://haml.info/), which is my favorite. Templates let you easily emit HTML with your code variables.

---

> The syntax was somewhat as follows: something('h1.myTitle').html 'My custom title' (it was very very much like jQuery

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><h1 class="myTitle">My custom title</h1></body></html>')
doc.at('h1.myTitle').content # => "My custom title"
```

or:

```
doc.search('h1.myTitle').each do |n|
  puts n.text
end
# >> My custom title
```

Yeah, I can see how that doesn't look like what you're talking about.

Comment: Uhm it's definitely not that one. The syntax was somewhat as follows: something('h1.myTitle').html 'My custom title' (it was very very much like jQuery, and had a very nice way to load the templates too). Dam, I wish I could remember it's name...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org). Alternatives include [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) and [Handlebars](https://github.com/cowboyd/handlebars.rb). All of these provide “logic-less templates”, thus forcing you to put your logic elsewhere and to focus solely on rendering in your templates.